# Open linux terminal and run multiple tasks using perl script

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, gnome-terminal, perl

I am running these commands in perl script with purpose

1. Open a linux terminal
2. Run script xbrecoverBoard.sh and rest_board.sh in that terminal

```
gnome-terminal -x sh -c "./xbrecoverBoard.sh && ./rest_board.sh";
gnome-terminal -x sh -c "./xbrecoverBoard.sh;./rest_board.sh";
```

For some reason a terminal opens and closes very quick that seems not doing anything although it doesn't give any error in the main terminal that I run perl script.
Please help me to resolve the issue and show me how to hold that open terminal from command line.

Answer (score 0):

For simplicity sake, try:

```
./xbrecoverBoard.sh
```

If it crashes, try:

```
./xbrecoverBoard.sh &
```

This could be something as simple as a bogus line of code in the `perl` script.

Answer (score 0):

To keep the terminal open, hand it over to an interactive shell after you have run your commands:

```
gnome-terminal -x sh -c "./xbrecoverBoard.sh;./rest_board.sh; exec bash";
```

Here, I used Bash shell as an example. Now, the terminal won't close since the Shell is using it.